# How to get Wi-Fi working on HP ProBook 445 G10 with Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: wireless, 22.04, hp, iwlwifi, mediatek

I got a new HP ProBook 445 G10 and installed Ubuntu 22.04 on it yesterday. However Wi-Fi and Bluetooth didn't work. In the settings there was Bluetooth but it couldn't be turned on. Under Network Connections, there was no Wi-Fi, wireless or such. I've now spent many, many hours trying to get them working. The most success I've had was to swap the wireless adapter from my old HP ProBook 430 G4 to the new laptop - Bluetooth started working straightaway. Wi-Fi is still missing though. Would like to get the new laptop working with either of the adapters. There are no additional drivers available according to Software & Updates. I disabled Secure Boot. "Wireless Network Device (WLAN)" is enabled in BIOS.

Most of the information online hasn't helped much because either I don't understand the instructions (something that isn't obvious to me is omitted), some of the commands to be executed don't output what the instructions say they should or fail altogether and I can't figure out what the errors are about, or some of the tools or packages to be installed aren't available or aren't located.

**The new laptop's wireless adapter**

With this one I could get neither Wi-Fi or Bluetooth working. I used linux-hardware.org's probe to determine some specs of the adapter:

`PCI  14c3:0616:105b:e0db » / 02-80   MEDIATEK Corp.  MT7922 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter    network     mt7921e`

Let me know if you think that the `lspci` or `lshw` or similar output would help here. This page https://linux-hardware.org/?id=pci:14c3-0616-105b-e0db shows that kernel versions 5.17 - 6.3 should support this device. With `uname -r` I determined that my kernel version is 6.5.0-14-generic. So I don't know if that's too new or if the information on the page is not up to date. I either couldn't find anywhere drivers for this adapter or didn't know how to install them. I have a million tabs open related to this so I'm not exactly sure anymore what all I have tried. I also considered Windows drivers with NDISwrapper but couldn't install `ndisgtk` or `ndiswrapper` because `apt-get` couldn't find them.

**The old laptop's wireless adapter**

I figured that this one would be more likely to work since it worked flawlessly on the old laptop with Ubuntu 16.04. Here's some of the details printed on the adapter (there's more if it helps):

> [Intel logo] Model: 7265NGW
>
> Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265
>
> FCC ID: PD97265NG IC: 1000M-7265NG

As mentioned, Bluetooth works with this one but Wi-Fi doesn't. In my desperation I have also tried swapping the two connector cables for the adapter, because I read somewhere that somebody had Bluetooth work whichever way the cables were but Wi-Fi only with one of the two options. For me Bluetooth worked either way and Wi-Fi neither way. Below is what `lshw` shows (linux-hardware.org's probe doesn't seem to show anything related to the wireless connection). Below, I think (guess) the latter might be related to the wireless connection somehow because it disappeared when swapping the adapter cables (and the former has stayed the same regardless of the adapter hooked in).

```
pete@probook:~$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for pete: 
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0
       version: 15
       serial: 64:4e:d7:19:8e:72
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=6.5.0-14-generic firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:47 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:fb604000-fb604fff memory:fb600000-fb603fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: c
       logical name: enx7cb0c232149a
       serial: 7c:b0:c2:32:14:9a
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes ip=192.168.44.206 multicast=yes
```

Edit: As per chili555's suggestion, I executed the following commands and got the following output:

```
pete@probook:~$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
pete@probook:~$ sudo dmesg | grep mt7
[sudo] password for pete: 
pete@probook:~$
```

I would very much appreciate some help with this as I have no idea how to try to fix this mess (besides buying another wireless adapter chip). As mentioned, I've tried to follow countless instructions online but have failed, either because I don't understand something, the commands don't work as described or something is not available.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the results of these terminal commands: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and: `sudo dmesg | grep mt7` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @chili555, I edited the question. There was no output. Note that I only tried it for the old wireless adapter currently inside the laptop.

Comment: Check BIOS settings and see if WIFI/WLAN is disabled

Comment: Thanks @Jeremy31, but in BIOS "Wireless Network Device (WLAN)" is enabled.

Comment: "Note that I only tried it for the old wireless adapter" Then we really can't diagnose and fix the *new* wireless adapter, can we?

Comment: No we can't. Me being fine with either of the adapters working, not knowing if there would be further suggestions of commands to be tried out, and having spent most of the last 24 hours fighting with this laptop, I didn't feel like straightaway swapping the adapters again. However now I did and a miracle happened. I'll write an answer. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I would have used the Intel instead of the Mediatek, I had one of the Mediatek and it wasn't good at all and switched back to an Intel wifi

Comment: @Jeremy31, yeah I read something along the lines of Intel adapters typically being less troublesome than Mediatek ones. However, now that I removed the old Intel adapter from the new laptop and replaced it with the new Mediatek adapter, things magically started working. The old adapter still also works in the old laptop. I will consider swapping again only if the new laptop's wireless connections start acting up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched back to the new adapter which came with the new laptop and which I had less success with initially, to try out the suggested commands. However now Wi-Fi and Bluetooth are working! Unfortunately I have no idea how or why - it must've been some of the many, many things I tried last with the new adapter. I have spent most of the last 24 hours fighting with this laptop so I've had time to try and forget countless of solutions.

As far as I know, I didn't do anything particularly successful with the old adapter in, and I did do many, many reboots before that with the new adapter still in. One thing that comes to mind is that I tried the new adapter in the old laptop but I wonder how that could help.

A big relief but very dissatisfying.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04.3 recently had a kennel update to 6.5. Newer kernel have support for newer hardware.